# React props function is undefined when testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a react app that deals with budgeting and I have written the code for a BillContainer component and an AddBill component.

This is my code:

**BillContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import BillList from './BillList';
import AddBill from './AddBill';

class BillContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      bills: [
      ]
    }

    this.addBill = this.addBill.bind(this)
  }
  addBill(bill) {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      bills: state.bills.concat([bill])
    }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <AddBill addNew={this.addBill} />
        <BillList bills={this.state.bills} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BillContainer;
```

and **AddBill.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class AddBill extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      newBill: ''
    };

    this.updateNewBill = this.updateNewBill.bind(this)
    this.handleAddNew = this.handleAddNew.bind(this)
  }

  updateNewBill(e) {
    this.setState({
      newBill: e.target.value
    })
  }
  handleAddNew(bill) {
    this.props.addNew(this.state.newBill)
    this.setState({
      newBill: ''
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type='text'
          value={this.state.newBill}
          onChange={this.updateNewBill}
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleAddNew}> Add Bill </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default AddBill;
```

and this is my **AddBill.test.js** test:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import EnzymeAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import AddBill from '../components/AddBill';

let Sinon = require('sinon')

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new EnzymeAdapter() });

it('Adds a bill to the list', () => {
  const clickSpy = Sinon.spy(AddBill.prototype, 'handleAddNew');
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <AddBill />
  );
  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
  expect(clickSpy.calledOnce).toEqual(true)
})
```

Im trying to test that a new bill gets added when the Add Bill button is clicked. I've passed the addBill function as a prop but the test is throwing the error `TypeError: this.props.AddNew is not a function`.

How do I prevent the error message and and make `this.props.addNew()` not undefined?

Comment: once I also find this issue replace ` <button onClick={this.handleAddNew}> Add Bill </button>` with  <button onClick={this.handleAddNew.bind(this)}> Add Bill </button>

Comment: I changed the button as above, but the same error message still persists :(

Comment: You don't need to do that as you've bound in the constructor (which is better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jest.spyOn` like so:

```
it('Adds a bill to the list', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <AddBill addNew={() => {}} />
  );
  const clickSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'handleAddNew');
  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
  expect(clickSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the test seems to be working but it isnt calling the spy. It's returning the error `Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.` do you have any ideas as to why this would be?

Comment: @Dan what if i am testing a stateless component? instance() wont work right? how would I simulate the click in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing an addNew property:

```
const wrapper = shallow(
  <AddBill addNew={yourAddNewFunction} />
);
```

Comment: So, in this instance yourAddNewFunction would be the sinon spy? I added 
`<AddBill addNew={clickSpy}/>`
 but I still have the same error message, am I missing something?